# How to find point of intersection between quadratic and a logarithmic equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How would I go about finding the point of intersection between $y=\ln(x)$ and $y=-x^2$

I've tried equating the two and solving, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: You're right that there's a unique solution to this system, but I'm afraid you'll only have to approximate this solution to within some accuracy. What do you need this for?

Comment: You are incorrect @Allawonder, I have given the exact solution in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$-x^2=\ln{(x)}$$
$$-x^2=\frac12\ln{(x^2)}$$
$$-2x^2=\ln{(x^2)}$$
$$e^{-2x^2}=x^2$$
$$x^2e^{2x^2}=1$$
$$2x^2e^{2x^2}=2$$
$$2x^2=W_k(2)$$
$$\therefore x=\sqrt{\frac12W_k(2)}$$
Where $W_k(z)$ is the $k$th branch of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). The only branch of $W_k(z)$ for which the original equation is true using the principal valued complex natural logarithm is the principal branch $(k=0)$ which also gives the only real value of $x$ as
$$x=\sqrt{\frac12W_0(2)}\approx0.6529186404$$
A link to the exact value can be found [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%7B0.5productlog(0,2)%7D) in arbitrary precision.